# JSP page is running MySQL query twice on Tomcat

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I am getting this weird problem where a MySQL insert is happening twice. I kept pairing down the code until I had the simplest version, but it's still happening. Has anyone seen this before? This is on a Tomcat server.

Below is my super-simplified code. When I run this, two entries appear in the table withe same value. The strange thing is it seems to run the whole page twice, because if I do a select quickly enough I can see the first entry by itself, then seconds later the second entry appears. When I timestamp the rows, they are 1-ish seconds different.

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydatabase",
        "myusername", 
        "mypassword"
    );
    java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();;
    statement.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_test (Value) VALUES ('Test value')");
%>
```

Additional info:
Also if I execute a select statement after the insert and select the complete contents of the table, only the first entry shows up. But when I look in the database, there are two entires. So it's like the whole jsp page finishes running, then runs again silently in the background.

Here is an expanded version of the code that allows you to choose the input value for the database, so you can try this out on the fly and see what's happening:

```
<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://***/***",
        "***", 
        "***!"
    );
    java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    String Value = request.getParameter("Value");
    statement.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_test (Value) VALUES ('" + Value + "');");
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_test;");

    while (rs.next()) {
        %><%=rs.getString("ID")%>=<%=rs.getString("Value")%><BR><%
    }
%>
```

You can try out this code at:
http://familychurch.life/familychurch/test.jsp?Value=Whatever

(Replace "Whatever" with the value you want to insert.)

Run it once and you'll see the value inserted once. But run it a second time, and you will see that the value you entered before is now in the table twice.

Comment: Also if I execute a select statement after the insert and select the complete contents of the table, only the first entry shows up. But when I look in the database, there are two entires. So it's like the whole jsp page finishes running, then runs again silently in the background.

Comment: It sounds like something is running this code twice rather than this actually causing 2 row to be inserted

Comment: So basically the code you show us is of no use to us. You will have to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, the page is running twice. But this is literally all that is in the code file. Nothing else. I point my browser at this page and the described behavior occurs. So this is all the code I need help with.

Comment: Here's a version of the code you can try out to see the effect:

Comment: ```<%
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
 java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:mysql://***/***",
  "***", 
  "***!"
 );
 java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
 String Value = request.getParameter("Value");
 statement.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_test (Value) VALUES ('" + Value + "');");
 java.sql.ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_test;");
 
 while (rs.next()) {
  %><%=rs.getString("ID")%>=<%=rs.getString("Value")%><BR><%
 }
%>

Comment: You can run it from here:
http://familychurch.life/familychurch/test.jsp?Value=Whatever

Comment: Replace the word "Whatever" with a value you would like to insert

Comment: Is `Luuk` your other account? Otherwise why would @Luuk be editing your question to add what appears to be additional information ???

Comment: Luuk suggested moving my first comment into the body of the question. This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, so I'm learning as I go!

Comment: @RiggsFolly hopefully I have provided enough context to see the issue now. Would you mind un-downvoting so I have a chance of getting an answer? This has been driving me crazy for a couple of days, and I need the community's experience and wisdom.

Comment: I only get ONE new row when I run that link

Comment: Okay, what the heck. @RiggsFolly I see you entering values, but it isn't doing what it's doing on mine. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Except when I entered `50=Numpty` only  one appeared and it still has not duplicated

Comment: And only one `53=RiggsFolly2JustToCheck`

Comment: So bizarre. @RiggsFolly what browser are you using? I'm using Chrome 80.0.3987.149

Comment: Okay, I just tried it in Safari and it doesn't happen.

Comment: Okay, that''s definitely enough for me to go on. Thank you so much for your help @RiggsFolly!

Comment: I see your Chrome isn't cause issues.

Comment: No, hope the tests give you enogh info to go on. Does not seem to be browser related.

Comment: Also tried quick suvccessive repeats and the long wait between tries, also does not seem to be that which is causing issues

Comment: I disabled a couple of extensions I don't use, and the problem went away. Wow! Thanks again @RiggsFolly

Comment: Do that one by one to find out which one is causing your issue

Comment: Will do. Thanks again!

Comment: @RiggsFolly would you mind upvoting this question? I have no reputation on StackOverflow at the moment, so it would be a big help (as opposed to my first and only question having a -1 score - lol)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was caused by a Chrome extension (Video Downloader for FaceBook™). It must have been reloading the page silently in the background.

Special shout-out to @RiggsFolly for helping me figure it out!